# how to remove spaces and underscores from a string in kdb?

Tags: kdb

How do I remove spaces and underscores from a string?

```
Input String: 
s:"Monday comes_after Sunday";

Expected Output:
"MondaycomesafterSunday"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Want to look at the special characters section of https://code.kx.com/v2/kb/regex/

```
q)s:"Monday comes_after Sunday";
q)ssr[s;"[ _]";""]
"MondaycomesafterSunday"
```

alternatively could use except which is generally going to be faster if only removing characters

```
q)s except " _"
"MondaycomesafterSunday"
q)\ts:100000 s except " _"
90 816
q)\ts:100000 ssr[s;"[ _]";""]
691 1072
```